# Connect to SQL Server Database from PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, connection-string

I have looked around online for a while now and found many similar problems but for some reason I can't seem to get this working.

I am just trying to connect to a SQL server database and output the query results to a file - See PowerShell script below. What I am uncertain about is how to integrate the User ID and Password into the connection string.

```
$SQLServer = "aaaa.database.windows.net"
$SQLDBName = "Database"
$uid ="john"
$pwd = "pwd123"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from table;"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "C:\Scripts\xxxx.csv"
```

The following error message is received:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server."

Comment: What version of SQL are you running?

Comment: sql server management studio 2012

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a SQL Azure instance?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 isn't a "version of SQL" - it's an application that can connect to and manage SQL Server, and it can connect to **any** version of SQL Server from 2000 (maybe older) through 2014.

Comment: version of sql ... sql 2000 ... sql 2012 ... irrelevant but thanks for your comment

Comment: No this is on-premises sql 2012 cluster.

Comment: ssms just like powershell if i launch AS another user it works but only because of integration.

Comment: I know I can do some powershell stuff to run as another user but what I want to do is just pass in a active directory username / password.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change Integrated security to false in the connection string.

You can check/verify this by opening up the SQL management studio with the username/password you have and see if you can connect/open the database from there. NOTE! Could be a firewall issue as well.

Answer (score 38):

`Integrated Security` and `User ID` \ `Password` authentication are mutually exclusive. To connect to SQL Server as the user running the code, remove `User ID` and `Password` from your connection string:

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"
```

To connect with specific credentials, remove `Integrated Security`:

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
# Database Interaction

$SQLServer = "YourServerName" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances!
$SQLDBName = "YourDBName"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; 
User ID= YourUserID; Password= YourPassword" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = 'StoredProcName'
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$SqlConnection.Close() 

#End :Database Interaction
clear
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer are as below for Window authentication

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *can* use integrated security, you can remove the user id and pass:

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"
```

Answer (score 1):

To connect to SQL Server as an active directory user just start the PowerShell as an active directory user and connect to SQL Server with `TrustedSecurity=true`

Answer (score 0):

I did remove integrated security ... my goal is to log onto a sql server using a connection string WITH active directory username / password.  When I do that it always fails.  Does not matter the format ... sam company\user ... upn whatever@company.com ... basic username.

Answer (score -1):

I think that may work only if the specific user in question is explicitly set up to log in with a password on the SQL server database i.e. without inheriting credentials from integrated Windows / single-sign-on