# Database lookup table Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

I have below PowerShell logic to copy the data. Now we are moving this logic to the Angular application.

So, I want to save this data in the database table. Could you please advise how can I store them?

In the application, if the user selects the country value, then it should automatically populate the State, Outlook, and Teams Column

```
if (country -eq "US") {
    $State = "Yes"
    $outlook = "Office 365"
    $Teams = "Office 365"
}
elseif (Country -eq "UK") {
    $state = "NO"
    $outlook = "Exchange"
    $team = Skype
}
```

Comment: Uhm, lookup means reading data but you're talking about saving stuff. Take a look at [Connect to SQL Server Database from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682703) to get an idea. To provide an actual answer we should get more information.

Comment: "In the application, if the user selects the country value, then it should automatically populate the State, Outlook, and Teams Column" Have you worked out how you implement this in Angular? Angular is worlds apart from Powershell. Also there is a whole world of data modelling questions here. Do you have a lot of different "Outlook" and "team" settings?

Comment: Yes. We have many data which we pull from CSV file. Can I create the same structure in DB